# How to get multiple vendor directories with composer?

Tags: php, javascript, composer-php

My project relies on ZF and on a JS library. I wanted to be able to deploy the ZF library to the normal location (vendor/zendframework/zendframework1) but then deploy my JS library to somewhere else (public/my-vendor/my-library). Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I came across the symlink idea but I wanted to automate this instead of manually creating the symlinks. I was going to create a composer script to create the symlink. I then found that symlinks on Windows and *nix need to be created in different ways which made this solution get messier by the second. I found that in the composer docs they talk about this same type of issue on the custom installers page and say that to solve this to create your own custom installer.

- Relavent docs section: http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/custom-installers.md
- My custom installer: https://github.com/ddelrio1986/zf1-public-asset-installer

Answer (score 6):

Composer is meant to manage your PHP dependencies, not JS.

Also, it only supports one vendor folder.

You might follow the way Symfony bundles use:

- install everything in vendor
- link (or copy) public assets to a public directory as part of your deployment process

In my opinion it's safer than installing something in a public folder (as long as you copy/link public part of a library only).

Comment: Very much +1 for suggesting a symlink, that would be my preferred way of working!

Comment: I like this solution but I am going to accept mine since it is what the docs for composer say to do for wanting to install certain packages outside of the vendor folder.

Comment: I might have not clearly stated this but this is exactly what I meant. Forgot to mention composer's installers though. Glad it works!

Comment: Also, for such a simple task as copying/linking you can use scripts: http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented this composer plugin to install packages into user (custom) defined folders you can just include it in your composer.json, follow the example and tell me if you have more questions :)

https://github.com/mnsami/composer-custom-directory-installer

## composer-custom-directory-installer

A composer plugin, to install differenty types of composer packages in custom directories outside the default composer default installation path which is in the `vendor` folder.

This is not another `composer-installer` library for supporting non-composer package types i.e. `application` .. etc. This is only to add the flexability of installing composer packages outside the vendor folder. This package only supports `composer` package types,

https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#type

> The type of the package. It defaults to library.
>
> Package types are used for custom installation logic. If you have a package that needs some special logic, you can define a custom type. This could be a symfony-bundle, a wordpress-plugin or a typo3-module. These types will all be specific to certain projects, and they will need to provide an installer capable of installing packages of that type.

### How to use

- Include the composer plugin into your `composer.json` `require` section::

```json
"require":{
    "php": ">=5.3",
    "mnsami/composer-custom-directory-installer": "1.1.*",
    "monolog/monolog": "*"
  }
```

- In the `extra` section define the custom directory you want to the package to be installed in::

```json
  "extra":{
    "installer-paths":{
      "./monolog/": ["monolog/monolog"]
    }
```

by adding the `installer-paths` part, you are telling composer to install the `monolog` package inside the `monolog` folder in your root directory.

- As an added new feature, we have added more flexibility in defining your download directory same like the `composer/installers`, in other words you can use variables like `{$vendor}` and `{$name}` in your `installer-path` section:

```json
"extra": {
    "installer-paths": {
        "./customlibs/{$vendor}/db/{$name}": ["doctrine/orm"]
    }
}
```

the above will manage to install the `doctrine/orm` package in the root folder of your project, under `customlibs`.

### Note

Composer `type: project` is not supported in this installer, as packages with type `project` only make sense to be used with application shells like `symfony/framework-standard-edition`, to be required by another package.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Composer reads `composer.json` schema. But, it can also use a different file. For instance, you can have `zendframework.json` and `my-library.json`.

In the `zendframework.json`, you can define:

```json
  "config": {
    "vendor-dir": "zendframework/vendor"
  },
```

In the `my-library.json`, you can define:

```json
  "config": {
    "vendor-dir": "my-library/vendor"
  },
```

Finally, you can update the libraries in this way:

```sh
COMPOSER=zendframework.json composer update
COMPOSER=my-library.json composer update
```

This is a simple idea. The benefit is that you solve the issue without third-party tools.