# How can i change to location where composer creates the vendor folder

Tags: php, composer-php

I have project's folder `dummyProject` and inside of it two folders, `src` and `test`, and `composer.json` file. Problem is when i run the `composer install` command the `vendor` folder being created in the `dummyProject` folder. How can i tell composer to create the `vendor` folder inside `src`?? thx..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to specify Composer install path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883374/how-to-specify-composer-install-path)

Comment: This answers how to change the name of the folder that we want to serve us instead of `vendor`...i am trying how to figure how to tell composer to create the vendor folder in a different path

Answer (score 7):

According to the following: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/composer-dev/CS_I0FNMHwY

You can set a Vendor Path like so:

```
{ 
  "config": { 
    "vendor-dir": "libs/" 
  } 
}
```

Looking at this question [How to get multiple vendor directories with composer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11925946/how-to-get-multiple-vendor-directories-with-composer), it appears you cannot set two different paths for vendor files (not sure if you will need to do this also), but the questions shows that with a symlnk this can be achieved.

Also see the following regarding changing the vendor location:
[How to specify Composer install path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883374/how-to-specify-composer-install-path)