# New to Composer and Yii2

Tags: yii, composer-php

I've started using Yii2 and subsequently Composer. Using Composer to install a package it puts it in the `project-root/vendor` directory. Does it have to be in the vendor directory in the 'basic' directory or does it not matter?

Also, if I set `"config" : {"vendor-dir" : "basic/vendor"}` in the composer.json and run `composer install` it installs the packages from the JSON file in the directory, but it uninstalls the packages Yii installed.

One other thing, when installing `Foundationize` (without setting the vendor directory) it installs dependencies `yiisoft` as well, which already already exists in the `basic/vendor` directory - duplicates of the same dependency.

So, is it required to install packages in the `basic/vendor` directory? If so, is there a way to have Composer install packages in the `basic/vendor` directory without uninstalling other packages?

Comment: Maybe this is what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11925946/how-to-get-multiple-vendor-directories-with-composer

Comment: That doesn't answer any of my questions.